# Valet - phpMyAdmin throws 404 not found

Tags: laravel-5, phpmyadmin, laravel-valet

Before installing Laravel and Valet on my dev environment (Ubuntu), I had installed PHP 7, MySQL and phpMyAdmin and everything was working fine.

In order to install Valet I had to disable `apache2` as Valet was complaining during the instalation and add nginx and follow these steps https://github.com/cpriego/valet-linux/wiki/Requirements:%20Ubuntu

However after the instalation when I try to access the phpMyAdmin through the browser I'm getting the default white page `404 - not found`. How can I fix this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have parked your workspace directory using

```
valet park
```

Clone the phpmyadmin repository using

```
git clone https://github.com/phpmyadmin/phpmyadmin --depth=1
cd phpmyadmin
composer install
```

In the same directory just download `phpmyadmin` package & extract it. You will be able to access it from

```
http://phpmyadmin.test
```

Comment: By "download phpmyadmin package & extract it" you mean run again `$ sudo apt-get install phpmyadmin php-mbstring php-gettext`, right ?

Comment: No. Download it from [github](https://github.com/phpmyadmin/phpmyadmin/releases) & extract it.

Comment: after cloning I have to run composer install command to make this work

Comment: valet link will make it phpmyadmin.dev which google owns now you should use valet park to make it phpmyadmin.test

Comment: Funny thing, nobody read what's around the code.

Answer (score 3):

If you have *phpmyadmin* already installed from your last setup, you don't have to download it & install it again.
I was facing the same thing migrating to *valet* from *lamp*, this is what I did:

1- Navigate to original phpmyadmin folder

```
cd /usr/share/phpmyadmin
```

2- Then add a link to valet

```
valet link
```

Hooray! you can now access it at: **phpmyadmin.test**

Comment: That actually works without a custom `LocalValetDriver.php` file. Cool!

Comment: use valet park because valet link makes the domain .dev

Comment: @AhmedAboud `valet link` works for me perfectly to have access at `phpmyadmin.test`. Probably you're using Valet+ and not only Valet.

Answer (score 0):

If you changed a port 8080. You can try this

localhost:8080/phpmyadmin/

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score -1):

I tried this and it failed to work for me, I found a workaround, check the link for my solution: https://stackoverflow.com/a/47211246/8768078