# Laravel valet phpmyadmin 404 error

Tags: laravel, phpmyadmin

When I use laravel new project I can access my website to link at project.dev. But when I wanna go to my phpmyadmin I get a 404 not found page. 
I already installed mysql through homebrew.

Comment: Which environment are you using? Probably you are missing the virtual host to phpmyadmin

Comment: Give more information, where are you trying to access and how? I would recommend you to try `mysql -uroot -p` in you terminal first to check everything is correctly installed

Comment: I'm working on a mac environment and if i try mysql -uroot -p i get this error ERROR 1045 (28000): Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: YES)

Comment: @StefanieSmet If you are using password type it right after the `-p` flag like `mysql -uroot -pYourPassword` (if you are using mac I would recommend you Sequel Pro to manage your dbs)

Comment: @Asur But I don't have a password.

Answer (score 1):

The best solution is to make a symbolic link to the phpMyAdmin folder like this...

> ***sudo ln -s /usr/share/phpmyadmin /path/for/your/valet.***

Then you can access your phpMyAdmin using the http://phpmyadmin.dev or whatever your valet domain is configured to. This works perfectly!

Answer (score 0):

This is how easy to install PHPMyAdmin with Laravel Valet on Mac OS

phpmyadmin with Laravel Valet on Mac OS

1. brew install phpmyadmin
2. cd /usr/local/share/phpmyadmin
3. valet link
4. valet secure

Now visit: https://phpmyadmin.test